# Cannot find module '@gradio/client' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: node.js, vscode-extensions, gradio, gradio-chatinterface

**This is the error that i am encountering**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNP36.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0q9u.png)
**My Package.json**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UADMd.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6imK.png)

I have tries multiple versions of gradio/client including 0.7.0 and 0.10.0
but nothing is working